# Temporary Storage Vector

Tags: excel, vba

The "A" is the matrix from the worksheet. How do count the columns in a matrix and create a temporary storage vector at N columns.

```
Public Function Array_ASolve(A As Variant, y As Range, p As Range, w As Double) As Variant
  Dim dA() As Double, dy() As Double, dx() As Double, dxx() As Double, dz() As Double, dp() As Double, dv() As Double
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, N As Long
```

Comment: you can get  the number of columns using `Ubound(A, 2)` and the number of rows by using `Ubound(A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to my previous homework.

```
If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then
    N = A.Columns.Count ' Error checking for LU as range goes here (NxN, numerical).
Else
    N = UBound(A) ' Error checking for LU as variant array goes here (NxN, numerical).
End If
```

You can make a temporary storage doing this

```
ReDim dy(1 To N)
```